# Restriction of dominant morphism on open subset is dominant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, morphism

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two varieties and $f: X \to Y$ is a dominant morphism (i.e. $\overline{f(X)} = Y$) between them. Prove that for any nonempty open subset $U \subset X$, the restriction $f|_U : U \to Y$ is dominant.

I have observed that many textbooks takes this for granted. For example, they sometimes substitute $X$ and $Y$ with appropriate open subsets of them without explaining why they could do this.

The only thing I know $\overline{U} = X$ and $\overline{f(X)} = Y$, but how to continue?

Any suggestion is welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of what is going on is purely topological.

Recall the following fact, which is true in general for any continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ between topological space (it is in fact equivalent to continuity I believe): for any subset $S \subset X$ , one has $f(\overline{S})\subset \overline{f(S)}$.

**If $U$ is a dense set in $X$, then $f(U)$ is dense in $\overline{f(X)}$**.
Indeed, we compute
$$\overline{f(X)}=\overline{f(\overline{U})}\subset \overline{f(U)}$$
hence $\overline{f(X)} \subset \overline{f(U)}$.

In particular, **a dominant continuous map between topological spaces is still dominant when you restrict to a dense subset**
From this you see that in you initial question all you need is open sets being dense. This is always the case for open sets of irreducible varieties (I can tell you why if you need but try to do it as an exercise first).

Comment: Thanks for your enlightenment! I tried to consider the generic point instead of the whole map. But I am not sure whether the generic point will be excluded while taking the open subset. Is there some property that guarantees this?

Comment: @LastingHowling yes indeed: generic points are included in all open sets (apply their definition).

Comment: I see now. I am not quite familiar with the concept of generic points. Thanks a lot for your patience!